# Unable to get complaints on closing tags

Tags: angular

I am Learning angular2 these days. I added below code to my Component

```
@Component({
selector: 'events-app',
template: `
    <nav-bar><nav-bar>
    <events-list></events-list>
`
})
```

As you can see i forgot to Close tag for Component `nav-bar`. Strange that angular didnt threw any error. Also when page rendered it didnt list anything that is inside Component `events-list`

Why is that?

**Update1**
Here is `events-list` Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

 @Component({
selector: 'events-list',
template: `
    <div>
       <event-thumbnail [event]= "event1"></event-thumbnail>

    </div>
`
})

export class EventsListComponent{
event1 = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Angular connect1',
    date: '9/26/2017',
    time: '10:00 am',
    price: '800'
  }

}
```

Here is `nav-bar` component

```
@Component({
selector: 'nav-bar',
templateUrl: 'app/nav/navbar.component.html',
styles:[`
    .nav.navbar-nav {font-size: 15px;}
    #searchForm {margin-right: 100px;}
    @media (max-width: 1200px){#searchForm {display:none}}
`

]
})

export class NavBarComponent{

}
```

Comment: Can you also add definiton of `events-list` component?

Comment: closing tags is a html matter, also what should be rendered in events-list? - provide the code if you expect an answer

Comment: Html supports tags without closing tags such as the input tag. That's why you don't get any warning.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha updated question. I didnt understood why People downvoting. It was simple question asked and i dont understand why i need to add code for Components?

Comment: If your component is not rendering the problem is probably located in your component.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the dev-tools ('element' tab in chrome) proving that the components does not render at all?

Comment: @Vega i know i forgot and thats why i asked question. When i forget to Close tag then why it does not render NeXT component

Answer (score 2):

Html can support tags without closing tags and custom components can be supplied without closing tags.

To understand the reason why you don't see template of `events-list` component let's rewrite template

```html
<nav-bar><nav-bar>
<events-list></events-list>
```

as follows:

```html
<nav-bar>
  <navbar>
    <events-list></events-list>
```

We can see that `event-list` is a child of `navbar` that is child of another `nav-bar`.

You can try it here https://alexzuza.github.io/enjoy-ng-parser/ Just change template.

So if your `navbar` component doesn't have `ng-content` `events-list` won't be displayed

So your template should be:

```html
<nav-bar></nav-bar>
<events-list></events-list>
```

Comment: what is ng-content? in my nav-bar Component i dont have any ng-content

Comment: Read this https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content

Comment: i dont know what it is to do With my question

Comment: It means that your `events-list` is removed from dom because it's child for `nav-bar`

Comment: how to add that ng-content to nav-bar?

Comment: If `events-list` should be inside `nav-bar` then add `ng-content` to `nav-bar` template. If they are siblings then use the last code from my answer i.e. close `nav-bar` tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155235/discussion-between-happy-and-yurzui).